# using dotnet ef without .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a Web API 2 solution with the fat framework 461.

I want to use EF Core because EF6's generated SQL is so painful ...

It's work, except when I try to use migration tools of EF Core. 
According to this [Migrations - EF Core with ASP.NET Core MVC tutorial (4 of 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations), I'm able to use PMC with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools installed. I've installed it, but I can't reference DotNetCliToolReference on a we api 2 service :(

Sadly, I can't use .NetCore, not approved by someone in my client company :(
Moreover, I can't use VS2017 only VS2015.

So, anyone has a solution for me tu use .NetCore ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.